# Automatically run Command before visual studio debug start

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, npm, cmd

I am developing a web application in asp core 3.1.
and I am using react js in the project with server-side rendering.

But every time I di some changes in my react code. I have to rebuild the project manually by running this comment

```
npm run-script build
```

Is there any way. I can make put this command at automation.

So then I go for debugging. Does visual studio automatically run this command before starting the debugging process?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use project `Build Events`. Right click on the project, select `Properties -> Build Events` and enter your script into `Pre-build event`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. working perfectly and in the same way as I was expecting :)

Comment: Is there also something like before launch/debug? @sourabhdevpura I want to serve my angular app after launch, but just build it on build